# What is the best free announcements app?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

My company I'm working for has custom coding locked down, so I can only work with the provided settings and apps. I'm looking for a good announcements/memo/updates app to put on a site page. I feel like the basic SP announcements app provided for a team site is rather plain. Is there a more... glamorous app on the sharepoint store any of you know about?

Comment: They can't really lock down custom coding, with a text editor, you could create whatever JSLink customizations you'd want.

Comment: If you know how to use XSL you can create your own custom stylesheet sheets and attach them to an announcements List View Web Part.